# how do I get Left-justified text in my bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, horizontal-alignment, natbib

Using the `natbib` package, how do I get left-justified text? Here is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,appendix}
\usepackage{fullpage,lipsum,multirow}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{float,soul}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Instead of posting your whole preamble it's preferable to construct  a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: To solve your problem you can try adding `\raggedright` just before your `\bibliography` command.

Comment: You might also want to try using the `ragged2e` package and its `\RaggedRight` command.  It will do a "better" job than the default `\raggedright` in that it will hyphenate with more frequency than the lowercase version of the command.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the foregoing answers: The `\bibhang` parameter might also be of interest for you. With `\setlength{\bibhang}{0em}` you can set the indention depth. Furthermore there is the parameter `\bibsep` to influence the spacing between entries.